# Strange IIS 10 error

Tags: iis

Getting a strange IIS error (Windows 10 Professional, IIS 10) on my development PC from even a simple ASPX page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ASPX page (including above) returns a 500 error with the following exception/stack trace:

```
[IOException: The file cannot be accessed by the system.
]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +1143
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1242
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +126
   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.get_CompilerName() +130
   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +826
   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +185
   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +2032
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +357
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +12029645
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +52
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +341

[HttpException (0x80004005): The file cannot be accessed by the system.
]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +76
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +631
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +38
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +758

[HttpException (0x80004005): The file cannot be accessed by the system.
]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +122
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +737
```

The system used to work properly as of about 6 days ago: Only changes are the latest windows update (version 1903)--yeah haven't ruled that out.

Old .ASP pages load correctly and I've verified that the system is loading/accessing the ASPX config files (web.config, global.asax, etc.).

Also tried uninstalling/reinstalling IIS to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Sheesh: my IIS directory path is contained within dropbox and dropbox decided to smart sync some of the roslyn files out. Thus IIS couldn't access them since the names were merely placeholders.